# Reading an XML file in Java, for Android & IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to read an xml file in to my android application to get data from it. I asked questions previously and found I need to use a parser. Using Google I managed to find ways to do it but for some unknown reason to me my file will not even read. Am I doing something wrong with the file path? I have tried many different ways with the file path but all lead to the same IO Exception. Also testing .exists() returns false :/, it does exist and will come up in a browser if I enter the exact same URL as the one in my code.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class XMLReader {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/simondobson/GoogleDrive/GUESTLIST/TGN/src/com/TGN/simon/events.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am calling the class like so in one of my activities.

```
XMLReader xml;
xml = new XMLReader();
```

Comment: Can you add in the stack trace that has the IO Exception?

Comment: You have to learn how paths work to create any application.  If you can't, it'll be agonizing frustration.

Comment: Showing the stack trace will still help, so we can show you how to read it. If you know how to properly read a stack trace, and how to respond to it, you can debug your applications faster/better in the future.

Comment: I moved the file to a simpler path and tried again no luck. Stack trace (1/2)

07-05 15:23:58.262: INFO/System.out(666): STACK TRACE
07-05 15:23:58.272: WARN/System.err(666): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/simondobson/events.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-05 15:23:58.322: WARN/System.err(666): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
07-05 15:23:58.322: WARN/System.err(666): at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)

Comment: 07-05 15:23:58.352: WARN/System.err(666): at libcore.net.url.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:82)
07-05 15:23:58.352: WARN/System.err(666): at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:117)
07-05 15:23:58.352: WARN/System.err(666): at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:183)
07-05 15:23:58.372: WARN/System.err(666): at com.TGN.simon.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:19)
07-05 15:23:58.372: WARN/System.err(666): at com.TGN.simon.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:40)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely stems from the fact that you are on a Windows OS, and file seperators use backslashes not forward slashes.

> "For Microsoft Windows platforms, the prefix of a pathname that
>   contains a drive specifier consists of the drive letter followed by
>   ":" and possibly followed by "\" if the pathname is absolute. The
>   prefix of a UNC pathname is "\\"; the hostname and the share name
>   are the first two names in the name sequence. A relative pathname that
>   does not specify a drive has no prefix"

[From the File Class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

MKYong also has [a good intro tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-construct-a-file-path-in-java/) to using the File Class in Java, and shows how to make your program find a file correctly on both Windows and Unix based platforms.

Comment: I am using Mac OS X, I just copied the file path and pasted. I just tried // and still doesn't work

Comment: You really should read the [File Class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html). Specifically the parts about using user.dir and File.seperator. Reading doesn't hurt :). Also make sure that your path has the correct cases, since the path is case-sensitive.